# threading cannot handle the following tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, selenium, python-multithreading

i tried to create a threading to login with a lot of usage, using python Threading, but I got a little error, my code can't handle the following task, I have 10 users, and run threading with threading, python code stops after 2 user logins, and the rest cannot be called, some code please add to fix this problem

```
python
print (variable)
```

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import numpy as np
from csv import reader

def Login_browser(i):

    id_str = ids_pass_list[i][0]
    id_pass = ids_pass_list[i][1]
    print(i)
    print("Login Id: ", id_str)
    print("Login Password: ", id_pass)

    Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    Options.add_argument('--app-https://google.com')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options)

    driver.get('http://localhost/login2/index.php')
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        
        driver.get('http://localhost/login2/index.php')
        time.sleep(1)

        email_field = driver.find_element_by_name("userid")
        email_field.send_keys(id_str)
        time.sleep(3)

        password_field = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
        password_field.send_keys(id_pass)
        time.sleep(3)
    

        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/button[1]")
        submit.click()
        time.sleep(30)


        driver.quit()
    except:
        time.sleep(10)


Page_Thread = 2
threads = []


with open('user.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)

    total_Len = len(list_of_rows)
    ids_pass_list = list_of_rows


for i in range(Page_Thread):
    threads += [threading.Thread(target=Login_browser,args={i},)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join
print ( 'succses')
```

Comment: Re, "python code stops after 2 user logins" and "`Page_Thread = 2`". Is that possibly the whole problem, right there?

Comment: P.S., I don't know anything about building services with Selenium, but a classic multi-client server has just _one_ thread that just listens for new connections, and it spins up a new "client thread" to serve each one. At any given moment, the number of live threads is equal to the number of connected clients, plus the one "listener" thread. A slightly more sophisticated version avoids the overhead of creating and destroying client threads by using a [_thread pool_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor).

Comment: i mean want to do Looping indeed a lot of uploaders in 2 threads only